# Confusion regarding finding invariant factors of a matrix.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

So I'm having a bit of trouble determining invariant factors of a matrix. Say we have
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 &0 &0 \\
0 &9 &0 \\
0 &0 &6
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and I want to find the invariant factors over $\mathbb{Z}$. In this case, would it just be the diagonal of the Smith Normal Form, i.e. 1, 6, and 18?
I'm mostly confused because all of our in-class discussions have mentioned that invariant factors are polynomials, in which case we examine
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2-x &0 &0 \\
0 &9-x &0 \\
0 &0 &6-x
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which would give $(2-x)(6-x)(9-x)$.

So I guess my question is if I'm interpreting the following correctly: If we are looking for factors over a PID not realized as a polynomial ring (i.e. $\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q}$, etc.), then the invariant factors are numbers, and if we are looking over a polynomial ring that's a PID ($F[x]$ where $F$ is a PID), then I should examine the second matrix above and find them that way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a matrix with integer coefficients, it may be considered a matrix in $\mathcal M_n(\mathbf Z)$, and its invariant factors  are  the invariant factors as a matrix in a PID.

Or it may be considered as the matrix of endomorphism of, say, $\mathbf R^2$. Which vector space is also a $F[X]$-module ($F=\mathbf{R,  C}$ or $\mathbf Q$), via $X\cdot x=u(x)$, i.e. a module over a PID. It is generally its invariant factors as a $K[X]$-modules which are polynomials, and they're called its *similitude invariants*.

The last similitude invariant is the minimal polynomial of the endomorphism, and the product of all similitude invariants is its characteristic polynomial.

Comment: "...and its invariant factors are the invariant factors as a matrix in a PID" means that the invariant factors are elements of that PID, i.e. in my example, I should go with the first interpretation (reporting integers as my answer), correct?

Comment: Yes, they're the invariant factors of an endomorphism of $\mathbf Z^3$.

Comment: The model is the theory of finitely generated abelian groups.